# Node.js catch-all route with redirect always renders index page with Angular regardless of url

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

Essentially when I use a catch-all route and use `res.redirect('/')` regardless of the url I enter it will always render the index/home page (ie Angular does not seem to 'see' the full url) however if I place `res.render('index')` in the catch-all route everything works fine. I don't want repeat code and redirecting to '/' should work, I have probably made a stupid mistake somewhere here and any help would be much appreciated!

Angular routing:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
    .when('/', 
        {   
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.jade'
        })
    .when('/about', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.jade'
        })
    .otherwise( {redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

This will correctly render the about page when entering `site-address/about`:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.name);
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

This will always just show the index page:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.name);
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Configuration if it helps:

```
// Configuration
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

When you use `res.redirect('/')`, Node/Express is sending an HTTP redirect, which will change the URL in the browser, thus when your index template is rendered, and when the angular code is run, the URL is `/`, regardless of what the user entered (the whole point of the redirect).

When you omit the redirect and just send the template as a response, NodeJs responds  with an HTTP 200 (success) along with HTML content. Since the URL didn't change, when your application runs, the angular routing properly routes.

EDIT TO ADD: Address Comment

Rather than have two routes render the same template, I would get rid of the `/` route all together, and just have the catch-all render the index template, which will then turn control over to the Angular router.

Otherwise, I would consider splitting your routes conceptually: All your application routes are specifically sent to angular router, and you render static routes via nodejs, and use your catch all to render a more appropriate page for a missing or unknown resource (more helpful for your users).

You can use regex-like languages to specify a single handler:

```
app.get('/()|(about)|(contact)/',function(req,res) {/* handle */});
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, makes sense! So is repeating the response to a request to '/' in the catch-all route the best way around this?

Comment: I'll address this in my answer.

Comment: Great idea! Except for me that did not work without a tweak

`app.get('/(|about|contact)',function(req,res) {/* handle */});`

The way you have it up there the OR is split into
- /()
- about
- contact/

But what you really need is 
- /
- /about
- /contact

I don't think the capturing brackets are necessary for the routing either.

Answer (score 3):

For folder structure:

```
root
-web.js
-dist/index.html
-dist/rest of the page
```

Just paste the following snippet to your `web.js`

```
nodeApp.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
nodeApp.get('/[^\.]+$', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        .sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
```

Comment: thanks this answer really helped me, just that I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem where when I use the catch-all routing, all of my static assets (stylesheets, javascript files etc) don't load:

```
app.use(app.router);   
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, frontend.app)));

// when this is removed, I can load static assets just fine
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.render('main');
});
```

When the app.get('*', ...) part is removed, I can load the static assets just fine (i.e. I can type in 'examplejavascript.js' and see the javascript file. When it is there however, express catches the assets.

Answer (score 0):

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
are you sure your requests are hitting the nodejs server. using this means, angularjs will try to search for urlmapping inside browser.

try by commenting 
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);