# Angular URL's not working but ui-sref does

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

So this may be a dumb mistake but I have an angularJs application and I have ui-router changing the states.  I am able to navigate to the different pages by `ui-sref` and `$state.go()` but for some reason if I type the url directly into the browser I get back the error `cannot GET ...`.  I have no clue why, but here is the config code and a state setup:

App Config:

```
.config(function ( $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

});
```

Items Page component/controller/state config:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';


angular.module('app')
.component("itemPage",{
templateUrl: 'app/itemPage/itemPage.html',
controller: itemPageCtrl
})
.config(['$stateProvider',function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('item', {
    url: '/item',
    template: '<item-page></item-page>'
  });
}]);



function itemPageCtrl(){
var ctrl = this;


}


})();
```

Just to reiterate, if I am the main page of my site and I click a button I can get to items page with `ui-sref or $state.go()` but if I try to put the url directly in `localhost:9000/item` or if I am already on the page and click refresh it gives the `cannot GET /item` message.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and I can give more code if needed. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a config on your server to redirect all requests to the entry point file (usually your `index.html`), using a `.htaccess` file for example in Apache.

This question was already made sometimes;

[Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)

Configuring on an Apache server: [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)

Configuring on a Node server: [Node.js catch-all route with redirect always renders index page with Angular regardless of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370606/node-js-catch-all-route-with-redirect-always-renders-index-page-with-angular-reg)